# Problem Management solution

Tags: issue-tracker

I’m seeking suggestions or recommendations for Problem Management.

Sadly, googling just reveals an endless list of wannabees: bug trackers, call management and project management software. Yes, what I'm looking for has a lot of overlap with these, but it’s critical that it includes the capability to

- identify individual reported cases
- aggregate individual reports into problems
- favour data over metadata in the UI
- routing of work based on queues – not assignment to individuals
- extensible meta data

Comment: I don’t know this domain – would it be a Web application? If yes, should it be for self-hosting?

Comment: @symcbean This Question is intriguing but needs more detail. Can you give more description, perhaps some examples. Please explain how various products do not meet your needs.